# If first part of file name matches file in folder returns 1 or 0 in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, file, loops, if-statement

I want to search for files based off of a range of cells with the beginning of the file name.

I would then like for the macro to return a 1 or 0 next to the file name if it is present or not.

My sheet is set up with files names in A2:A29 and I would like to return 1 and 0 for files being present or not in B2:B29

I have started trying to write the macro but I am stuck. Please help

```
Sub SiteSignal()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As Range
folderPath = "C:\Users\RobEi\Documents\MWAM_Eisenrich\Client_Data\Sacramento\Sacramento_Flow_Pressure"
Filename = ("A2:A29")

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies, Yes I am trying to write a macro in MS excel to loop through a set of files in a folder and return 1 or 0 if the file is present or not

Comment: There should probably be a `vba` or `vb.net` tag on this question, but I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I will adjust the tags

Comment: ***I have started trying*** Where?

Comment: This is all I got       Sub SiteSignal()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As Range
folderPath = "C:\Users\RobEi\Documents\MWAM_Eisenrich\Client_Data\Sacramento\Sacramento_Flow_Pressure"
Filename = ("A2:A29")

End Sub

Comment: Alas, I don't see any of your efforts, so I conclude that you have no idea where start from. SO is not a free coding service, so put some of your efforts, please.

Answer (score 2):

- Loop through `A2:A29` - use `Offset` to write to `B2:B29`.
- Concatenate your `folderPath` and the value in each cell and the wildcard `"*"`, then use the [`Dir` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function) to check whether a file exists that matches that pattern.
- If there's a match, the `Len` of the `String` returned will be `> 0`.
- `Abs(TRUE)` returns 1; `Abs(FALSE)` returns 0.

---

```
 Sub SiteSignal()

    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim Filename As Range, rng As Range

    folderPath = "C:\Users\RobEi\Documents\MWAM_Eisenrich\Client_Data\Sacramento\Sacramento_Flow_Pressure"
    Set Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A2:A29")

    For Each rng In Filename
        rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Abs(Len(Dir(folderPath & "\" & rng.Value & "*")) > 0)
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: I am very new to this so I am going to ask a lot of dumb questions. How were you able to do this with out using a loop statement or a do while statement? How were you able to return 0 or 1 for only part of the file name?

Comment: So there is `For Each` loop... If `A2:A29` have the beginning of the file name, then use the wildcard `"*"` to match the rest of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. In A1 put the name of the file. In A2 the pathway to the folder that you are searching. A3 will give you the true or false as to whether it was found

```
Sub main()
Dim strFile                             As String
Dim inputDirectoryToScanForFile         As String
Dim primaryFile                         As String
Dim foundFile                           As Boolean

    Filename = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    inputDirectoryToScanForFile = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

    strFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "*")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        If strFile = Filename Then
            foundFile = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = foundFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above should work, but here is another one :D

```
Sub SiteSignal()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\RobEi\Documents\MWAM_Eisenrich\Client_Data\Sacramento\Sacramento_Flow_Pressure")

For i = 2 To 29
Range("B" & i) = 0
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, Len(Range("A" & i))) = Range("A" & i) Then
        Range("B" & i) = 1
        Else
        End If
    Next objFile
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: at BigBens post ( I can not comment there)
The loop is the "for each... next. " the ranke.value is the part of the name and "*" is a wild card. And the abs vrings the 0 and 1